# How to build a form

Tags: java, forms, swing

I have used a GridBagLayou to arrange on a panel couple of labels and text fields. Now I need to add 2 buttons below text fields beside each other on the right hand side. How can I do it?
I think that I need to use other panel, layout them there and then somehow glue those 2 panels? But how? Am I thinking right?

Edited:
@Hego555 - if you have nothing to say don't bother to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of layout to which you are referring is typically called a 'nested layout'.

See this [nested layout example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271) for some tips.  E.G. the combo and checkbox on the top-right of the GUI sound like how you want the two buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, to make form's you use JPanel, and JLabel and all that good stuff... try this [link](http://bit.ly/tmMEoo)